# Prestashop Installation failed

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

UPDATE [RESOLVED]

Make sure your php.ini max_execution_time is set to 300 
Make sure you chmod 777 /var/lib/php/session

I tried to install prestashop 1.7.1 on a fresh serveur (Running with nginx) by at 67% the install crash when prestashop try to install Module Addons.

I tried to increase the memory_limit to 256M and max_execution_time to 90 but once again the install failed.

I didn't made a screenshot but i have the exact same result with this sreen found on the web :

[image]

Someone know why i get this error ?

Comment: Try to use another instance of the installation pack, it can be a problem with your archive or particular version

Comment: thanks man i will try tonight ! i let you know

Comment: the only thing is the version was instaled correctly on my locahost but not on the serveur host...

Comment: Ok, then. Do you have the same PHP versions on your servers? Because of developers often forget about differences between PHP versions and work preferably with the newest ones so it also can cause the problem

Comment: I have the same PHP versions in my case it's PHP 7.1. On the server side i use PHP-FPM but not localy, i don't know if it's make a big difference.

Comment: I don't think so. Did you try to install another(newer) version?

Comment: I will try to install the version 1.7.3 when i come home in 3 hours then i let me know man, thanks a lot for your interest

Comment: did you look in the error log on the server?

Comment: It's now working, i modified max_execution_time to 300 then i had to ch mod -R 777 /var/lib/php/session then it was installed correctly.  thanks so much friends :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to increase the server resources.

A more punctual fix is editing this file BEFORE BEGGINING THE INSTALL PROCESS:

*/classes/Tools.php

Find this function:

```
public static function addonsRequest($request, $params = [])
```

and change this slice of code:

```
 if (!self::$is_addons_up) {
           return false; 
        }
```

to this:

```
/*if (!self::$is_addons_up) {
               return false; 
            }*/
return false;
```